# Getting the value of option chosen by the user

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In my index file where the form and function are located, named:

**index.php**

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "invtype.php",
        data: "getrevenuetype=true",
        success: function(b){
            $("#revenueType").html(b)
        }
    })
})
```

`<span name="revenueType" id="revenueType"></span><br/>`

**invtype.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("","","") or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname");

if(isset($_POST['getrevenuetype'])) {
    $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chartofaccount WHERE accountnumber >= 4000 and accountnumber <= 4999");
    $acct = '';
    $acctrow = mysql_num_rows($sql3);
    if($acctrow > 0) {

    echo 'Revenue Type:<select name="rename">';
        while($chartrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
        $revenueaccountname = $chartrow['accountname'];

    $acct .= '<option value="$revenueaccountname"> '. $revenueaccountname .' </option>';

    }

    }
}

echo $acct;
echo '</select>';
```

My question is how will I get or what code should I put on to get the value of the option selected by the user? My purpose in getting the value is that I want to put it in another php where it will be used as var in inserting data into MySQL. already tried this code: `$name = $_POST['rename'];` then included 'invtype.php'; on the other php file (this is where I will use the value of option selected) but it doesn't seem to work. I know my code is all messed up and I'm really sorry about it, but guys if you can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey... Asking others to write code instead of you - it is not fair... ;)

Comment: i'm not asking for others to write the codes for me, that is why i put my codes here. im asking to help me analyze my codes so i can correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to  add , for example, ' for first time response

```
echo $acct;
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit id="submit" value="" />';
```

than add  js

```
$('#sumbit').click(function(){
 var name = $('select[name=rename]').val();

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "invtype.php",
      data: "rename=1&name="+name,
      success: function(b){
        $("#revenueType").html(b)
    }
   })

});
```

than change invtype.php

```
if(isset($_POST['rename'])) {
 $name = $_POST['name'];

 //work with base 
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for the response @voodoo417, but there is still a problem, after i followed your advice, my select option has been gone and also the additional submit button doesn't appear. if it isn't too much too ask, can you look at it again thank you

Comment: sorry, change  $('#sumbit').click(function(){ to $('#sumbit').live('click',function(){

Comment: bacause is dynamically element

Comment: and change behaviour onSuccess on secord ajax request ( after working database , its copypaste ;))

Answer (score 0):

How's this?
Give your form an id attribute and replace the formid with it :)

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "invtype.php",
        data: "getrevenuetype=true&selectedoption=" + $('#formid option:selected').val(),
        success: function(b){
            $("#revenueType").html(b)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: May be: `data: {"getrevenuetype" : true, "selectedoption" : $('#formid option:selected').val() },` ?

Answer (score 0):

After the `select` tag is added to the page and an `option` is selected by the user, you can then send the selected value with a button click like this:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server.php",
        data: "value=" + $('option:selected').val(),
        success: function(b){
            alert('Sent successfully!');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="rename"] option:select').val()
```